# Google sheet cell is only writen once instead of multiple times

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to make a visual random number genarator. That means in Cell F4 should random numbers   shuffle trough until it stops with a random number.
My Problem is now, that i can only see the last number generated and not the shuffeling.

```js
function Wuerfeln() {

  var Upperbound = 60;
  var Lowerbound = 1;
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 10 + 1) + 10);
  var RandomNummber = 0;
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("F4");

  while(i>0)
  {
    RandomNummber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Upperbound - Lowerbound + 1) + Lowerbound);
    range.setValue(RandomNummber);
    i--;
    Utilities.sleep(200);
  };
};
```

Comment: Maybe `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` can help you

Comment: yes that works thanks. But sadly its way to slow, even when i remove the sleep() entirely

Comment: I would suggest that you try to do this in a dialog where you can do the intermediate steps in html possibly with a setInterval function to display the intermediate steps.  Using spreadsheetapp flush is always going to be slow and combersome for the end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sheets has a minimum refresh time, you're not going to make it change super fast by design.

Many requests from a script get batched together and run at the same time, so when the edits are all in the same cell you do not see them change and only the last one is displayed.

The ***only*** way to force a cell to change is using `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` as suggested by [Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15611153/sergey). This forces all pending sheet changes to be pushed. As you have noted however, this is slow.

To do this at all you would need to have an HTML dialog or sidebar which can run JavaScript that directly changes the HTML elements rather than a cell in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you define a few things and then try it out until it looks like you want, or what you could do is create a pop up which shows a .gif of a dice.

The first approach would look like this

```
function wurfel(){
   const timeDelay = 200
   const numbersToShowUntilFinal = 20 // or do a random num

   // then your code here, 
   // but using the variables above to test around until you found a cool 

}
```